# Fuses of motorbike

Tags: indicators

My motorbike Xl 125 all indicators, horn, lights turned off after fuse number 10 cut off and I replaced with new but it cut off after 2 days. What is a problem?

Comment: Have you fitted a higher rated headlight bulb? If not, then you may have a short circuit somewhere - does it blow after hitting a bump for example?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to find the issue is to put a bulb in place of the fuse - while it is lit the fault is there, then you can disconnect items or gently move the wires until it goes out - hopefully then the fault is apparent...

Use a bulb that takes less current that the fuse you are trying to test a 55W headlight bulb is about 5A... So a small side light bulb 5W is about 0.5A...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a short-circuit somewhere. Did you do any work related to indicator, horn, etc. recently?

Start by doing a visual inspection of wires. Pay special attention around narrow bends and where wires move (between frame and steering column.)